# How to Remove Back Slashes from JSON Response in C#?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services, rest

I have written a webservice which converts the XML Response of a TP-Open Service into JSON format. I am new to WCF and writing Webservice.
But the converted JSON format displays as follow.

```
"{ \"data\": { \"current_condition\": [ {\"cloudcover\": \"25\", \"humidity\": \"48\", \"observation_time..
```

How to Remove these back slashes \ and my code so far.

```
   public string checkweather(string q, string num_of_day)
    {
         HttpWebRequest request=..;
               ...
        string Url = string.Format("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q={0}&format={1}&num_of_days={2}&key={3}", q, format, num_of_days, key);
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        Request.Method = "GET";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var result2=reader.ReadToEnd();
         }}}
          return result2;
         }
```

Please inform me if you need more information.

Comment: Is result2 the string you are talking about? I'm guessing return result2.Replace(@"\", "");

Comment: is this just copy/pasted from debugging? Because it looks like the backslashes are just escaping characters

Comment: @ofstream, I tried but no changes in the result.

Comment: just treat the Json as it is, they are escaping the `"` character.

Comment: You'll see tha backslashes always when you are printing it, but it will for just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your JSON is fine, the backslashes are escaping the quotations, which people have said. The following code shows some valid XML -> Json converting. (Using Json.NET)

```
const string xml = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>";
XmlDocument node = new XmlDocument();
node.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(node);
```

If you view in debug mode, you will see the backslashes, but the output is valid Json.

Output

```
{"note":{"to":"Tove","from":"Jani","heading":"Reminder","body":"Don't forget me this weekend!"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample example. I changed the return type into stream. It is working now.

Comment: @Thiri I know this is an old question but I seem to be having the same issue. What do you mean by "changed the return type into stream"?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure there are backslashes in your string? It looks like me they are the escape characters because there are " characters in your string.

Comment: yes. Is there anyway to remove these backslashes after converting into JSON format ?

Comment: If they are just escape character they are not really in the string. It's just the C# way of embedding special characters in a string. Just like \n means a new line. You can use File.WriteAllText() to write the string to disk and see with Notepad what is really there.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = JToken.Parse(your string).ToString();
```

Comment: Please comment your answers, or they are likely to be recommended for deletion.

Comment: This also worked for me, could do with a bit of context though. If you've not heard of JToken before (I hadn't); it's part of the Newtonsoft.Json library (which you can easily install through Nuget)

Answer (score 0):

rest service time: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(JsonString);

response time: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(JsonString);

if your decoded code contains this string `\\"` then please replace `\\` to `\`